# Write LaTeX3 seq in aux file

Tags: expl3, auxiliary-files

The code below defines a macro `\addtothelist` that adds the name of a fruit and its color (this is just an example) to `\g_mylist_seq`. It also defines a macro `\printmylist` which prints all the items like:

- apple: red
- banana: yellow
  ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_mylist_seq

\newcommand{\addtothelist}[2]{
    \cs_gset:cpn {mylist#1} {#2}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_seq {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printmylist}{}
 {
  \seq_if_empty:NF \g_mylist_seq {
    \begin{itemize}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_mylist_seq {
      \item \use:c{mylist##1}:~##1
    }
    \end{itemize}
  }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addtothelist{red}{apple}
\addtothelist{yellow}{banana}
\printmylist

\addtothelist{orange}{orange}

\end{document}
```

However, it ignores `orange` because it is called after `\printmylist` is called. Can we use `aux` file to handle this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build the sequence when reading the `.aux` file, not when adding to the list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_mylist_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtothelist}{mm}
  {
    \iow_shipout:cn { @auxout } { \ADDTOTHELIST { #1 } { #2 } }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ADDTOTHELIST}{mm}
  {
   \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_seq { {#1}{#2} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printmylist}{}
  {
    \seq_if_empty:NF \g_mylist_seq
      {
        \begin{itemize}
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_mylist_seq { \mylist_print_item:nn ##1 }
        \end{itemize}
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mylist_print_item:nn
  {
    \item #1:~#2
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text

\addtothelist{red}{apple}
\addtothelist{yellow}{banana}
\printmylist

\addtothelist{orange}{orange}

\end{document}
```

The first run would produce nothing, but the second run will give the intended result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you even do not need to write the seq to the `aux`-file. You just need to write the `\addtothelist` commands to the `aux`-file, which could be done even without using `expl3` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_mylist_seq

\newcommand{\addtothelist}[2]{
    \cs_gset:cpn {mylist#1} {#2}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_mylist_seq {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printmylist}{}
 {
  \seq_if_empty:NF \g_mylist_seq {
    \begin{itemize}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_mylist_seq {
      \item \use:c{mylist##1}:~##1
    }
    \end{itemize}
  }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addtothelistindirect}[2]{%
  \protected@write{\@auxout}{}{\protect\addtothelist{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}}% write without expanding the arguments
}
% Alternative definitions:
% \newcommand{\addtothelistindirect}[2]{%
%   \write\@auxout{\detokenize{\addtothelist{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}}}% write without expanding the arguments
% }
% \newcommand{\addtothelistindirect}[2]{%
%   \protected@write{\@auxout}{}{\protect\addtothelist{#1}{#2}}% write with expansion of the argument unless \protect is used
% }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

You need at least one page of output, otherwise the write to the aux will
never happen.

\addtothelistindirect{red}{apple}
\addtothelistindirect{yellow}{banana}
\printmylist

\addtothelistindirect{orange}{orange}

\end{document}
```

After two LaTeX runs this shows:

[image]

If you instead want to write the seq to the `aux`-file this could be done with `\AtEndOfDocument`. But in this case you would need two sequences: One to be filled inside the document and be written to the `aux`-file and one to be read from the `aux` file at `\begin{document}` and be printed by `\printmylist`. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to remove entries without deleting the `aux`-file.